# making an existing C# application n-tier

Tags: c#-4.0

i am new to C#,I just want to understand the changes required to make my existing C# user n- tier.
In my current application i am restricting the second launch of Application with help of code.
i.e, if the application is running, then user cannot launch the application again.

But now the requirement is, if suppose there are two user on windows and i am running a application for one user and  I switch to another user then I am unable to launch the application.

so if I want to implement this what changes are required in the application.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: You want to allow multiple instances of your application (simple - remove the "help of code"). This has nothing to do with **n-tier**

Comment: n-tier would involve splitting your app into at least 3 processes that work together (often reside on different machines). One tier could deal exclusively with the database, while another tier could deal exclusively with business rules... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because i do not understand the n-tier part of your question.

But :
If you want to ensure only one instance of your apps is launched per user you can use a Mutex which is like a system-wide lock. Defining a mutex id per user (maybe using their windows login or something like that as key)

More info at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

N-Tiers apps means an app with so clear separation of concerns that the deployment of UI layer, business layer and data layer could be done on separate servers. They must handle serializations to manage exchange between tiers, is that what you need ?